# Обязательно ли закрывать Statement и ResultSet?

Tags: servlet, jdbc, java

Java сервлет при каждом вызове получает `Connection` с SQL базой данных (Oracle `oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver`, используя `DriverManager.getConnection()`), затем создает `Statement` и `ResultSet`. Все в локальных переменных. Очевидно (везде пишут об этом), что `Statement` и `ResultSet` надо закрывать.

Вопрос: будет ли утечка ресурсов, **если не закрыть** `ResultSet` или `Statement`?

**UPD** (в ответ на ответы).

Итак, Oracle XE development, соответственно, версия бесплатная, ограниченная (но настолько!)

Прежде всего, `Statement` и `ResultSet` в нормальном режиме я закрывал, а вот для `Exception(s)` ограничился только закрытием `Connection` в `try { ... } finally { ... }`

Поэтому для тестирования сначала выбросил `Statement` и `ResultSet close()` и в непрерывном цикле на 77 connection все свалилось, **но свалилось по причине `ORA-12519`. Не Могу ОТКРЫТЬ** новую connection!!! Вот те раз, я же их закрываю! Вернул все `close()` - то же самое. Я ведь в непрерывном цикле запросы не гонял, предположить такую подлянку не мог!

Пробую цикл с одним соединением (при закрытии `Statement` и `ResultSet`) все работает (1000000 циклов). Если не закрывать, сначала падает по `ResultSet`, потом по `Statement`.

Почитал про `ORA-12519` в сети, увеличил ресурсы (`alter system set processes=150 scope=spfile;`, это кому-то помогло) падение отодвинулось до 230 соединений и все.

Потом вычитал, оказалось, дело в том, что **ограничено количество соединений в единицу времени**. Сделал 100 в секунду - то идет, то валится. Сейчас идет с 50 в секунду (цикл 100000 после каждой сотни открытых-закрытых `sleep(2000)`) - YES - прошло.

Так что, спасибо всем!!!

**UPD-2**

Искал оптимальную задержку (при повторе попытки открыть новое соединение) оказалось 350 миллисекунд - для 1000 циклов у меня общая задержка в худшем случае 6.3 с. Почему-то она плавает, нет повторяемости. Для других задержек (от 50мс до 3с) общее время хуже.

Нет ли у кого идей, как правильно организовать подобные замеры?

**UPD-3**

Oracle - это загадка. Попробовал на работе с "боевой" 11.g Enterprise Edition на сервере.

Выполняется раз в 10 медленнее, поэтому гонял до 10000 циклов. **Нет сбоев!** Без разницы, закрываю `Statement` и `ResultSet` или нет. Работает и все тут (**без всяких `sleep()`**), хотя драйвер в программе тот же самый от XE Development.

**У кого-нибудь есть идеи???**  Как вообще правильно программировать взаимодействие с базой?

Comment: Переоткрыл (уже закрытый вчера) вопрос из-за обнаружившихся новых обстоятельств. Изложено в **UPD-3** вопроса.

Comment: 11ый Оракл не доводилось мучить, а вот 10ка загибалась :)
порог resultset'ов на 32к или 65к непомню уже точно. но это факт. 

Java API одного серьезного продукта имел уже реализованный менеджер для thread-safe задач. поэтому надо было лиш сгенерировать "таски" с runnables. к сожалению обработка ошибок небыла реализована правильно поэтому с каждым error'ом занятых ресурсов было все больше.

можете представить себе результат если к БД делалось 20 * (600к - 2кк) запросов :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Насчет `statement` не уверен, но точно знаю, что с `resultset` будет. Кажется, предел находится на 32к незакрытых `resultset`, oracle не сможет возвращать результаты выборки.

имхо, лучше всегда за собой убирать :)

Comment: Спасибо ! Ваш ответ подвиг меня на тестирование. Все так, Statement тоже закрывать **обязательно**. В **UPD** к вопросу опишу подробнее.

Answer (score 5):

Спецификация JDBC рекомендует всегда все закрывать вручную. Однако при этом утверждается, что

> all Statement objects will be closed when the connection that created them is closed

и что

> closing a Statement object will close and invalidate any instances of ResultSet produced by that Statement object

т.е. закрытие соединения *должно* закрыть все порожденные объекты иерархически. Однако авторы, видимо, решили перестраховаться и защитить вас от случаев, когда "должно" в реализации драйвера перетекает в "мы постараемся" - по техническим причинам либо из-за невнимательности. Видимо, специкация спецификацией, а на практике "всякое может быть" (как бы быдлокодно это не звучало) - так что лучше закрывать самостоятельно.

Лично ине кажется, что в драйвере Оракла тут все же будет ОК и с автоматическим закрытием, а вот при переходе на другую БД могут быть сюрпризы.

Comment: Спасибо ! С Oracle XE (development) все оказалось **далеко не OK**. См. UPD к вопросу.